# Sending Data from jQuery Ajax to MVC COntroller

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, controller

I am trying to send an SVG string from my index page to my controller. But it's getting a null value.

```
var str = "<svg height=\"350\" version=\"1.1\" ... svg properties ..."
console.log(str);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    //dataType: "text",
    url: window.location.origin + '/NavigationExport/GetSvgData',
    //data: '{"value":"' + str + '"}',
    data: {value :str},
}).done(function (data) {
    debugger
});
```

Here is my controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetSvgData(string value)
{
    return;
}
```

but this code is giving me a 500 internal server error.

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (`value="<svg height="350" ve..."`).
>
> Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is
>   potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script.
>   The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your
>   application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of
>   input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a
>   web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.

If I use

```
data: '{"value":"' + str + '"}'
```

it sends null value to the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because MVC thinks you're trying to send HTML in the request, and prevents it to stop any XSS attacks. You can allow HTML/XML by adding the `ValidateInput` annotation to Action. In your case, try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void GetSvgData(string value)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: But [AllowHtml] is only valid on 'Property' declarations only. Gives an error here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ValidateInput(false)] as action attribute in the controller to allow HTML string passing to action.

```
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {

    }
```